# Issue while uploading CSV file in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error while uploading csv file in mysql

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

My Query is:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$file=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle=fopen($file,"r");

while(($r=fgetcsv($handle,"500",",")) !==FALSE)
{

    $sql="insert into `couponss` (promoid,offerid,offername,type,code,title,description,category,offerpage,dateadded,expiry,exclusive,featured) values('" . implode("','",$r)."')";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    //echo implode("','",$r);
}
}
else
{
echo "NO DIRECT SCRIPT ALLOWED";
}
```

**This is what my csv file looks like**

```
P43183','1126','Giftease.com CPS - India','Coupon','GIFTICICI20','Get 20% Off on orders above INR 1200*','TnC: The offers are valid on all eligible orders placed between 1st April 2015 to 31st March 2017 The offers are available on all items ordered on www.giftease.com excluding gift cards/vouchers, select watches & gift wrapping charges. Offer limited to usage of the code to 3 orders per customer Eligible orders: the order value of a single order must be equal or higher than Rs. 1200 or Rs.4000 excluding any items belonging to the excluded categories mentioned above Coupon code \"GIFTICICI20\"" or \""GEICICI1000\"" must be applied in the shopping cart',' prior to payment for eligible orders',' in orders to avail the offer Eligible orders must be paid for using ICICI Bank credit card',' debit card or netbanking only. The offers cannot be combined with any other offer available on www.giftease.com from time to time. All order are subject to the terms of use of www.giftease.com published at http://www.giftease.com/terms-of-use. This offer may be withdrawn or modified at any time at the discretion of Giftease or ICICI Bank."','Gifts & Flowers','http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=1126&aff_id=51664&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.giftease.com%2F%3Futm_source%3Dvcommission%26utm_medium%3Dbanner_emailer%26utm_campaign','Sep 16, 2016','Mar 31, 2017','0','0',
```

**This is only the first row.I have around 500 rows like this in my csv file**

If i print the query before execution it shows data perfectly

**Executed Query**

```
insert into `couponss` (promoid,
                        offerid,
                        offername,
                        type,
                        code,
                        title,
                        description,
                        category,
                        offerpage,
                        dateadded,
                        expiry,
                        exclusive,
                        featured) 
            values('P43183',
                    '1126',
                    'Giftease.com CPS - India',
                    'Coupon',
                    'GIFTICICI20',
                    'Get 20% Off on orders above INR 1200*',
                    'TnC: The offers are valid on all eligible orders placed between 1st April 2015 to 31st March 2017 The offers are available on all items ordered on www.giftease.com excluding gift cards/vouchers, select watches & gift wrapping charges. Offer limited to usage of the code to 3 orders per customer Eligible orders: the order value of a single order must be equal or higher than Rs. 1200 or Rs.4000 excluding any items belonging to the excluded categories mentioned above Coupon code \"GIFTICICI20\"" or \""GEICICI1000\"" must be applied in the shopping cart',
                ' prior to payment for eligible orders',
                ' in orders to avail the offer Eligible orders must be paid for using ICICI Bank credit card',
                ' debit card or netbanking only. The offers cannot be combined with any other offer available on www.giftease.com from time to time. All order are subject to the terms of use of www.giftease.com published at http://www.giftease.com/terms-of-use. This offer may be withdrawn or modified at any time at the discretion of Giftease or ICICI Bank."',
                'Gifts & Flowers',
                'http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=1126&aff_id=51664&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.giftease.com%2F%3Futm_source%3Dvcommission%26utm_medium%3Dbanner_emailer%26utm_campaign',
                'Sep 16, 2016',
                'Mar 31, 2017',
                '0',
                '0')
```

Comment: First thing to try is to remove any trailing commas on the end of each line as it's expecting a value after that. If that don't work make sure you field types match your CSV entries, ie ints are numbers and varchars are strings etc. And just try it with a File with one or two rows to test it.

Comment: This would be the perfect time to use a `prepare()` once and `execute()` many times

Comment: If you echo the query **and show it to use** in your question it would be very useful. MYSQL does not make these errors up because its bored. **Obviously the query is not correct**

Comment: Your first entry is missing the leading ', but you can actually delete all of the ' as it's looking for entries between commas and expects it to match what the field type is defined as...

Comment: Did I mention that the number of columns in your Table has to match that in your CSV row... OH by the way I am talking about using phpmyadmin using import as CSV which is I just realised Not what you are trying to do... But it'll prove if your data matches...

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have edited my question. Added the executin query in the end

Comment: @TimBrownlaw if i use phpmyadmin to import csv file. It imports without any error

Comment: Good to know :) I'll keep quiet now. Cheers!

Comment: @A.R mistake happen in this place  'Sep 16, 2016','Mar 31, 2017','0','0',             input count is greater than column count

Comment: @shiva how to solve it?

Comment: AS I see it 13 column names and 16 data values  Guess what **Column count doesn't match value count**

Comment: '0','0', what is this ? if no need remove it

Comment: Also if your dates are being placed into DATETIME or TIMESTAMP columns they also are wrong..... Oh by the way they should be in DATETIME or TIMESTAMP columns

Comment: @shiva i need those values cant remove them... I think the issue is with the date as you said.. How to remove the commas from the date

Comment: **First rule of debugging** Make the code/data readable. Then you can simply see the error, definitely in this case

Comment: @RiggsFolly 'Sep 16, 2016','Mar 31, 2017' may be its because of this.. How can i remove those commas in my date

Comment: ITS BECAUSE YOU HAVE ONLY **13** column names and **16** data values ___The error message say it all___

Comment: Your dates will need to be converted to format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS`

Comment: check your excel column count first after that will look into insertion and make sure that if count is 13 check any single quotes in column values

Comment: in your loop find the date values and convert it and pass it                           $time =  strtotime("Sep 16, 2016");
$insertdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time); and save it into db

Comment: please please please don't put contents of an uploaded file directly in your query. Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have only 13 column names and more than 20 column data values in the mysql query.

Also make sure you use `` instead of '' while inserting cell value in mysql.

Also make sure you use mysqli_real_escape_string while inserting cell value in mysql.

Comment: I want to remove extra ," from my csv file except the comma for line separator

Comment: The use PHP's trim() to remove '' while preparing mysql insert query.. something like implode("','",trim($r, "'"))

Answer (score 0):

Check this Example hope it helps:

```
//  File read and storre start //
$tmpName = $_FILES['invitecollegescsv']['tmp_name'];
$instituteAarray = array_map('str_getcsv', file($tmpName));
foreach($instituteAarray as $k=>$v)
{
    if($k>0)
    {
    $InsertInvites = $conn->query("insert into r_job_invitations (id_job,email,inv_st,inv_res,inv_confirmation) values ('".$jobId."','".$v[0]."','".$inv_st."',0,'".$job_response."')");
    }
}
//   File read and store ends here   //
```